# Is there a way to get the name of a user in python on Mac?

Tags: python, file

I want to get the name of a user automatically to locate files such as `f'users/{username}/desktop/file` is there a way I can do this?

Comment: The linked duplicate was the first result when I Googled your question's exact title.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`getpass` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html):

`getpass.getuser()`

This works for both Unix and Windows.